# "The ignorance and the hubris (arrogance) of our adversaries is our biggest asset."

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, sentence-translation

I would like to translate the sentence

> The ignorance and the hubris (arrogance) of our adversaries is our biggest asset.

into Latin. Google translations do not seem to be entirely correct and I want to have it perfect. My rusty knowledge of Latin is from almost 30 years ago :-) Let me tweak it to these two versions:

> Ignorantia et superbia adversariorum maximum commodum nostrum est.
>
> Ignorantia et superbia adversariorum, hic nostrum commodum.

In the first version I am not sure if it is better to omit the "est" at the end. The second is a bit more loosely translated, but seems to be a bit more catchy. But is it correct, too?

Any comments from the experts are highly welcome. Thanks!

PS: Apart from that, since I am not a native English speaker, I am not sure if it's actually, "The ignorance and the hubris (arrogance) of our adversaries are our biggest assets." And this would also be reflected in the Latin sentence!

Comment: Btw., I have some doubts whether the translation of "asset" to "dignissim" (a word I didn't know so far) is correct. It is what google translates but I can't find another, reliable reference.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you explain in a bit more detail what you mean by "is our biggest asset"? After all, this is a somewhat broad metaphor in English; precision helps in translation. At a glance, your first translation would seem OK. In your second translation, is *hic* "here"? And what's up with masculine *noster*?

Comment: @Cerberus: Thanks for the input. Maybe in this context we could also understand "assets" as "weapons". But I was looking for something slightly broader. Which also includes "advantages" or "tools to be used". For the "hic noster": I thought "hic" could be used as meaning "This is our asset". And yes, it should be "nostrum" not noster, I've corrrected it.

Comment: @Cerberus: "This is our asset" in a sense of an exclamation, much like "Here they are...". In any case, I like the first version much more. So if this is OK, then I am happy with it :-)

Comment: OK, I understand! I've offered some suggestions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option would seem to be OK, except that I would read the beginning as the subject, whence *sunt*. The verb is indeed somewhat optional.

Your second one should probably have *hoc nostrum commodum* (neuter *hoc*) or *haec nostra commoda* (neuter plural). *Hoc/haec* would be the subject of the clause and should hence agree with the subject complement *commodum/commoda*.

A few more suggestions:

---

> Ignorantia superbiaque adversorum nobis maxime prosunt.

"We benefit the most from the ignorance and arrogance of our adversaries." *Adversorum* is shorter and means the same thing. Using *-que* is common with parallel words. *[Prosum](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=prosum%231&filter=CUTF8)* has just the right meaning:

> prō-sum, fŭi, prōdesse, v. n., *to be useful* or *of use*, *to do good, benefit, profit*.

---

> Ignorantia superbiaque adversorum, ecce arma nostra acerrima.

"The ignorance and arrogance of our adversaries, (behold) [these are] our sharpest/finest weapons." The metaphor of *arma* for "tools/means" is common enough in classical Latin (as in English).

---

> ... potestas maxima.

" ... greatest strength/power."

---

You could combine elements from different suggestions to make your own version.

Comment: Great! So I could combine it into "Ignorantia superbiaque adversorum nobis arma nostra acerrima." I do understand it right that "acerrimo/-a" is the adjective for "sharpest/finest", yes? (I like the connotation of "finest".)

Comment: @mathphd: Yes, that acerrima/us/um is correct. I would omit *nobis*, though, since you already have *nostra*.